# How to automate mvn install command

Tags: maven

normally, if I need to add new 3rd party dependency in maven project (which is not there in maven remote repo) , we use mvn install command manually to install 3rd party as maven coordinates.
how can we automate this process ... we want mvn install command to execute at runtime every time build is made ?

thanks

Comment: What kind of 3rd party dependencies are you talking about? Usually you use a repository manager and let the repo manager download everything which is needed from Maven Central...?

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest you to use a repository manager ([Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype), [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/), ...) to host your 3rd party dependencies.

Forcing developers to build 3rd party dependencies and install them to their local repositories (`mvn install`) before building the main project can be very tedious. You'll definitively don't want to automate that process, but rather use a repository manager to simplify it. You can find the benefits on [Maven documentation about repository management](https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html).